# T-SQL Select all from TableA and condition on TableB

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, join

```
TableA Columns: A_ID, NAME, SOURCE, TITLE, EVENTID
TableB Columns: B_ID, EVENTID, CODE, FIELD
```

How do I extract NAME, SOURCE, TITLE and FIELD or null (if there is CODE=x) ? Example should show it better. It's T-SQL on SQL Server Express.

**Example:**

```
TableA                                 |   TableB
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
A_ID, NAME, SOURCE, TITLE, EVENTID     |   B_ID, EVENTID, CODE, FIELD
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1     john  s1      x      100         |   1     100      5     textA  
2     bruce s2      y      105         |   2     100      10    textB
3     bob   s3      z      110         |   3     105      5     textC
                                       |   4     110      5     textD
                                       |   5     110      10    textE
```

There is no code 10 for EventId 105 so the result should be null. How do write a SELECT quesry that would give me such result:

```
[ john  | s1 | x | textB ]
[ bruce | s2 | y |       ]
[ bob   | s3 | z | textE ]
```

It might be really easy but I can't figure it out.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an `OUTER JOIN` between the tables

```
SELECT A.NAME,
       A.SOURCE,
       A.TITLE,
       B.FIELD
FROM   TableA A
       LEFT JOIN TableB B
         ON A.EVENTID = B.EVENTID
            AND B.CODE = 10
```

The `B.CODE = 10` condition needs to go in the `JOIN` not a `WHERE` clause to avoid effectively turning the query back into an `INNER JOIN`.

This can return multiple rows for a particular `A` value if there is more than one joining record but it is not clear from your question if this is possible in your data anyway (and if so which `B.Field` value should be used) and this may well be your desired behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Works too. There is always only one joining record. Can you tell me, is there a way I can expand this ON/AND to add 1 more column like this? For example for code 15 (if it exists, if not null). However, value would be again in FIELD just with different code..

Comment: @yosh - For one additional column I would just add  `LEFT JOIN TableB B2 ON A.EVENTID = B2.EVENTID AND B2.CODE = 15` to the query and `B2.FIELD` to the select list. If there was more I might consider a different approach.

Comment: Right, I didn't think of this :) I guess I just need 1-2 columns. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hey, can you tell me how would you do it in case there were more columns to be added...? Like display 3+ columns if their codes are in tableB.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
SELECT a.NAME, a.SOURCE, a.TITLE, b.FIELD 
  FROM TableA a
       LEFT JOIN TableB b ON b.EventId = a.EventId
             AND b.Code = 10
```